# socket.io web client: no error event on lost connection with the server?

Tags: javascript, events, browser, https, socket.io

When I intentionally stop my socketio server after my client web page is successfully connected (and exchanged messages with the socketio server),

**I'm NOT getting any `reconnect_error` or `error` event in javascript.**

The "send xhr" in socket.io fails and the browser console trace a sequence of errors like this:

```
GET https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNX9dim net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED polling-xhr.js:203 //
```

The client browser code foresee error event handlers:

```js
// index.js
var socket = io()

// ...
// ...
 
// socketio error handlers
// https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('socketio Connection successful')
})

socket.on('ping', () => {
  console.log('socketio ping from server')
})

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  console.log('socketio disconnect reason ' + reason)
})

socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
  console.log('socketio Connection error: ' + error)
})

socket.on('reconnect', (number) => {
  console.log('socketio reconnect attempt ' + number)
})

socket.on('reconnect_attempt', (number) => {
  console.log('socketio reconnect attempt ' + number)
})

socket.on('reconnect_failed', () => {
  console.log('socketio Connection Failed')
})

socket.on('reconnect_error', (error) => {
  console.log('socketio Connection error: ' + error)
})

socket.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('socketio error : ' + error)
})
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>...</title>
 <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

But there is no event generated.

Is this what is supposed to happen? Why there is not event generated?

I'm running last socket.io release (3.0.2) with default options and brave (Chrome 86 on Windows 10) browser.

BTW, my issue is like the very old (8 years ago): https://groups.google.com/g/socket_io/c/7BynuejEmts

Seems weird to me that is not yet fixed. Any idea?

---

**UPDATED**

I re-wrote the error handlers (double checking version 3 event names: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html), se the cient.js code updated.

Now, if I kill the socketio server, I finally got a `disconnect` event!

```
socketio disconnect reason transport close
```

That's the expected behavior.

**NOTE**

The `disconnect` socketio event is generated ONCE.

If the server remains down, the client doesn't raise an expected `reconnect_attempt` event. Still weird for me. Last minor related point, I still do not get the `ping` event.

thanks
giorgio

Comment: Weird, I have this code in one of my current projects and it works like a charm : `socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("IO connection lost!"))` I guess your problem doesn't come from the lines of code you posted, but elsewhere, like when do you initialize your socket, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Good news

it seems that the not detection of error was a socket.io bug! Now fixed in v. 3.0.5: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Now, catching `connect_error`:

```
socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
  console.log('socketio Connection error: ' + error)
})
```

I got an error ( `socketio Connection error: Error: xhr poll error` ), as expected!